# Serving two websites with the same Nginx on the same ubuntu server redirect to same website

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, nginx

I'm trying to serve two different websites on my **Ubuntu** **16.04** server.

This is the **Website1** configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/website1.com`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name website1.com www.website1.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name website1.com www.website1.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/website1.com.domain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/website1.com.intermediate.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1337;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

And this is the **Website2** configuration in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/website2.com`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name website2.com www.website2.com;
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        server_name website2.com www.website2.com;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/website2.com.domain.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/website2.com.intermediate.key;

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH';

        location / {
                proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

These two websites I'm trying to serve with `nginx` are two `nodejs` applications. One is listening on port `1337` (**website1**) and one on port `5000` (**website2**).

If I visit the url `https://website1.com` I access to the correct website, the **website1**.

If I visit the url `https://website2.com` I access to the wrong website, it shows me the **website1**, instead of the **website2**. (the url on the top bar is `http://website2.com`, with a warning for the `SSL`).

How can I serve two different websites using the same nginx service on the same **Ubuntu** server?

Comment: What's in your `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` directory? :)

Comment: The linked files in sites-available: `website1.com` and `website2.com`. I did this command `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/website1.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` and the same for `website2.com`

Comment: Might seem silly, but have you restarted/reloaded nginx `sudo service nginx reload` to tell it to use your 'new' config files?
Also `sudo nginx -t` is a winner for finding errors in your config files.

Comment: Sure, I did these steps... I think that could be a possible problem with SSL certificates... the strange thing is that if I remove `listen 443` part from config I get redirected everytime on `website1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The redirect problem is due to the invalid `SSL` certificate. I'm trying to figure out how to make it valid.

So, the `nginx` configuration is ok.