# Two domains configured to different websites in nginx point to the same website

Tags: nginx, web-hosting, nginx-config

I've got a server that I'm trying to host two websites on. One (site1) is a NextJS site, running through pm2. The other (site2) is just a plain html/css site. Site1 is using the root of my domain, and site2 has got its own subdomain.

The problem is, whenever i go to site2's subdomain, it still shows the contents of site1. The URL is correct, and according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55806008/16331315), it could be thanks to a SSL issue, however I'm using cloudflare and from what I can tell, one-level subdomains should still be covered by default.

Here are the nginx configs:

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site1:

```
server {
        server_name mydomain www.mydomain;
        listen 80;

        root /home/ubuntu/servers/site1/public;

        location / {
                try_files $uri @proxy;
        }

        location @proxy {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                proxy_pass_header Server;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_connect_timeout 3s;
                proxy_read_timeout 10s;
         }

}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/site2:

```
server {
  server_name site2.mydomain www.site2.mydomain;
  listen 81;

  root /home/ubuntu/servers/site2/;
  index index.html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri.html $uri $uri/ =404;
  }

}
```

I'm quite new to nginx so I may be missing something obvious, but I have tried:

- Having both configs in the same, or different files
- Using the same port for both sites (site2 returns a 403 from nginx)
- Using different ports (whats happening currently)
- Shutting off pm2 for site1 (cloudflare returns a 502)
- Removing `$uri/` from site2 config (nginx error 500)

Comment: Keep it simple - the 2nd site is unrelated to the first, right?  And unless you're doing something strange, you'll want it on port 80 (you mention SSL but there's no SSL config here so let's keep it simple)?  So, with port 80 in your config you get a 403? That could be explained by requesting `http://site2.mydomain` without an `index.html`, right?  You haven't specified an `index` file, and you haven't enalbed directory listing, so ... 403.  Another possibility is the permissions on site2's directories and files, have you checked the user nginx is running as can read them?